# C++ , Problem not working with numbers above 10^5

Tags: c++

whenever i try using R that is greater than 10^6, the console doesn't return anything. My goal is for Numbers of L,R,n,br to be able to work up to 10^18. thx for the help.
My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long L, R, br=0;
    double p,q,r;   
    cin>>p>>q>>r>>L>>R;
    for (long long n=L; n<=R; n++) {
        if (    
            ceil(n/p)+ceil(n/q)+ceil(n/r)<=n
        ){br++;}        
    }
    cout<<br;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe its time to debug to figure out why the console does not return a value.

Comment: Also you should name your variables better and explain what problem you are solving. I have no idea what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://onlinegdb.com/HyCJg0tbI
Input: 3 4 5 10000001 10000002
Output: 2

Comment: My guess would be, that it takes a very long time to iterate over more than 10^6 cycles. Our Processors run at around 3 GHz that means 3*10^9 Operations per second in the best of cases. Even if your loop would take just one cycle per iteration 10^18 iterations will take you 10 years to complete

Comment: A coworker of mine wrote a great blog post on what to do in this situation, [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It seems that you are trying to solve some online judge problem with a brute force approach. This is almost never the expected way. Could you please explain what the problem is?